# StackPanel height exceed parent Grid height

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have situation like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="fullGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="innerGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel x:Name="leftSide" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ItemsControl/ VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                </ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Problem is that `leftSide` stackPanel height is higher than it's parent: `innerGrid` height.

I was debugging it in Snoop and it seems that StackPanel just ignore it's `VerticalAlignment` property.

I would like to avoid setting `Heigh={Binding ElementName=xxx, Path=ActualHeight}` because I have some additional `Margins` inside, and it break the view.

How can I handle that?

Comment: Any particular reason you are wrapping the scroll viewer in a stack panel in the first place? The basic answer is that you can't do this, but there are workarounds

Comment: No reason for wrapping ScrollViewer. And removing it works! Could you explain me mechanics of that?

Comment: basically a StackPanel needs to determine it's size by it's children. Now the ScrollViewer inside of it doesn't report a size but needs it's parent to report a size to which the ScrollViewer will adjust itself. Since neither of the two controls get's what it needs they can't resize/render the way they should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ScrollViewer` fills its parent. `StackPanel` wants to size to its children, and so tells them they have as much space as they want (and then "shrinks to fit").

So, `StackPanel` tells `ScrollViewer` it can have all the space in the world, which it happily takes. There is no way to stop this besides doing a binding as you describe or setting an absolute height.

So the simple solution is: remove the `StackPanel`. Then the `ScrollViewer` will take up the space the `Grid` assigns it.